# How to load a value from a DataTable to Excel programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, excel, datatable, email-attachments

I am looking for an example to load create an Excel workbook that contains a single worksheet. The workbook needs to be created with a randomly generated name from a simple DataTable with ASP.NET MVC 4. Then I need to send the newly created Excel workbook as an email attachment. So the example needs to show how to create an email and send it to an SMTP server within ASP.NET MVC 4.

Can anyone help me with sample code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to export Dataset into Excel.
Here is a very simple function to export data without using excel object and other messy stuff.
XSL Transformation is applied to dataset and XML for excel is generated.
You have to pass it the DataSet to export and path to where file should be generated.

```
 public class WorkbookEngine
{
  public static void CreateWorkbook(DataSet ds, String path)
  {
    XmlDataDocument xmlDataDoc = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
    XslTransform xt = new XslTransform();
    StreamReader reader =new StreamReader(typeof(WorkbookEngine).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(typeof (WorkbookEngine), “Excel.xsl”));
    XmlTextReader xRdr = new XmlTextReader(reader);
    xt.Load(xRdr, null, null);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    xt.Transform(xmlDataDoc, null, sw, null);
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter (path + “\\Report.xls”);
    myWriter.Write (sw.ToString());
    myWriter.Close ();
 }
}
```

The links below contain more information that may help you:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/406704/Export-DataTable-to-Excel-with-Formatting-in-Cshar

Have a nice day.